# Can't add recyclerview to the fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, object, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

i can't add the RecyclerView to my fragment.
the super class "RecyclerView" appears in red color.
help me out!

java code:

```
package com.invincible.fragedit;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class TableList extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;//error line 
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_table,container,false);
    }
}
```

i have already attached a recyclerview in the xml file of fragment but i can't make object of RecyclerView in my fragment class

xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:id="@+id/frag_2"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:background="#c61414"
    tools:context="com.invincible.fragedit.ListTable">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/table_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you add the jar file as a library to the project?

Comment: Have you added the dependency `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'` in your `build.gradle` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add import into your fragment and check if you are added it into your build.gradle like this `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'`.

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
```

Comment: done! but still it is an error in the import package as well as in the fragment class

Answer (score 0):

make sure that in build.gradle You Add

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your java class import statement is missing for Recycler view. 
 Please do the following steps.

1- add following lines in build.gralde file 'compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1''.
2- clean and rebuild again.

3- Paste this line in your import section  'import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView';